# Read row from one dataframe and write it to the column of another

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to read a row from one dataframe and append that row of data into the column of another dataframe. The dimensions are compatible. How does one do that?

Define A & B as 3X3 frames:

```
A <- data.frame(c(1:3),c(4:6),c(7:9))
```

A is:

```
 c.1.3. c.4.6. c.7.9.
1      1      4      7
2      2      5      8
3      3      6      9

B <- data.frame(c(13:15),c(16:18),c(19:21))
```

B is:

```
 c.13.15. c.16.18. c.19.21.
1       13       16       19
2       14       17       20
3       15       18       21
```

I want to add the last row of B to a new column in A so that I get in A:

```
1      1      4      7    15
2      2      5      8    18
3      3      6      9    21
```

This works. Is there an easier way?

```
A[, 4] <- unlist(B[3, ])
A[,5] <- NULL
```

Comment: dataframes exist in multiple languages. Can you be more specific? Are you referring to R, python, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I am referring to R. I am constructing a dataframe to hold results from other data frames. I have an NXM data frame that holds my results. I am picking a row from a QXN data frame and I want to load this row into my NXM result data frame as a column. I have tried various schemes but I always get errors when I try and load the row vector as a column into the result data frame.

Comment: I do not need the Null assignment.  Only get a 4 column matrix in A. Also see that `A[,4] <- t(B[3,])` succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
i <- sample(nrow(NXM) , 1)  # pick a row, .... any row
NXM[ , i] <-  unlist( QXN[i, ] (
```

Or:

```
 A[,4] <- t( B[3,] )
```

There is the potential downside that the "lowest common type denominator" for the various column types of QXN will become the column type in `NXM`. The dataframe situation was a bit different than the matrix situation would have been.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn’t work. I defined a 3X3 data frame A and a 3X3 data frame B. I then typed:

    A[, 4] <- B[3, ]

I got this error:

Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 4, value = list(c.13.15. = 15L, c.16.18. = 18L,  :
  provided 3 variables to replace 1 variables

I even tried:

    A[,ncol(A)+1]<- B[nrow(B),]

and got this error message:

In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , ncol(A) + 1, value = list(c.13.15. = 15L,  :

Comment: You never offered a test case. You might need to wrap `unlist` around the RHS:   NXM[ , i] <- unlist(QXN[i, ])

Comment: Original post has been edited.

Comment: Adding unlist gives two new columns in the A frame, one is 15, 18, 21 and the next new column (#5) is 15, 15, 15